# Create URL and redirect?

Tags: forms

```
function news_article_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state)
{
// Make a URI link from title of pdf being uploaded
if (isset($form_state['values']['field_upload_import_pdf'])) {
    $file = file_load($node->field_upload_import_pdf['und'][0]['fid']);
    $filePath = file_create_url($file->uri);

    // Redirect to pdf
    isset($_GET['destination']);
    unset($_GET['destination']);
    if (isset($filePath)) {
        drupal_goto($filePath);

        // Return all field behaviors to redirect to default
    } else {
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'to page preview';
        drupal_redirect_form($form_state);
        }
    }
}
```

I was experimenting with `drupal_goto()` and `$form_state['redirect']`, but neither of them seems to work. Using `drupal_goto()` hijacks the whole module and the `$form_state['redirect']` doesn't do anything. Also I am getting PHP errors when `else` function encounters the first two lines of code above:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in news_article_node_submit()

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in news_article_node_submit()

Is there a way to create a URI from the filename, and redirect users to `domainname://NAME_OF_FILE.pdf` when choosing a conditional field while, at the same time, when users use any other conditional field, the behavior is the default Drupal one?

Comment: I know! Is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trick from the module File Force Download. You can check it in the their code repository https://cgit.drupalcode.org/file_force/tree/file_force.module?h=7.x-1.x